# TCL; saving multiple list with foreach command

Tags: list, for-loop, foreach, tcl

I do the following :

```
set q [list Phi1 Phi2 Phi3 Phi4 Phi5 Phi6 Phi7 Phi8 Phi9 Phi10 Phi11 Phi12 Phi13 Phi14 Phi15 Phi16 Phi17 Phi18 Phi19 Phi20 Phi21 Phi22 Phi23 Phi24 Phi25 Phi26 Phi27]
```

then I define my lists (from Phi1 to Phi27)

```
foreach l $q {
    for {set i 5} {$i<17} {incr i 1} {
        set fx1 [nodeEigenvector $i 1 1]
        set fy1 [nodeEigenvector $i 1 2]
        set frot1 [nodeEigenvector $i 1 3]
        lappend $l [list $fx1]
        lappend $l [list $fy1]
        lappend $l [list $frot1]
    }
}
```

Then I want to save those vector into a single file :

```
foreach aer $q {
    for {set re 1} {$re<27} {incr re 1} {
        set Mode $aer
        set fo [open Modd.out a]    
        puts $fo [list get $Mode]
        puts [list get $aer]
        close $fo
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I get a file with a list of "get Phi1" (27 times...) to Phi27...
funny fact, when I type the command `puts [list get $Phi1]` I do obtain my data as expected at screen. Anyone could help me?
If there is a simpler way to do it I'd like to know too !
(I am simply trying to build, populate, then save a matrix (27 vector)).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `list get` command.
You can get the value of the list by doing a `[set $aer]`.

`[set varname]` returns the value of `varname`, so if `aer` is set to `Phi1`, `[set $aer]` will return the value of `Phi1`.

Opening and closing your file every time is very inefficient, so I fixed that also.

So the last loop becomes:

```
set fo [open Modd.out a] ; # or mode w    
foreach aer $q {
   puts $fo [set $aer]
   puts [set $aer]
}
close $fo
```

You can rewrite this to use the [dict](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) command.

```
set phi [dict create]
foreach l $q {
    for {set i 5} {$i<17} {incr i 1} {
        set fx1 [nodeEigenvector $i 1 1]
        set fy1 [nodeEigenvector $i 1 2]
        set frot1 [nodeEigenvector $i 1 3]
        dict lappend phi $l [list $fx1 $fy1 $frot1]
        # or another way:
        # dict lappend phi $l $fx1 $fy1 $frot1
    }
}

puts $phi
puts [dict get $phi Phi2]
```

The dictionary can be structured in different ways depending on how
you need to access your matrix.

Comment: Also, if you are using variable names in variables (except when feeding into `upvar`), consider whether an array would be a better solution. Though a dictionary as you show works too.